# Cannot install python wheel file in conda without sudo

Tags: pip, conda, python-wheel, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to build PyTorch from a `.whl` file on a jetson nano.

I am able to build and install the file but only while using `sudo`, attempting to `pip install` the file without sudo results in this error:

```
ERROR: torch-1.10.0a0+git36449ea-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

This is strange as with admin I have no issues installing this file, but I can then only use the library by using the `sudo` command before going into or running with the `python` command.

I should note that this is in a conda environment, but even in the base conda environment this issue still occurs.

It seems like I can also install the package by using `conda deactivate` to deactivate conda.

I am using Python 3.7 in the conda environment and Python 3.6 outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Python 3.7 in the conda environment and Python 3.6 outside.

This is the issue. You have a `cp36` whl file, so python 3.6. I am suspecting that when you run `sudo pip`, your systems `pip` is invoked, whereas when you run `pip`, then `pip` from your `conda env` is used, and cannot install a python 3.6 whl to a python 3.7 env.

Either you need to get the `cp37` whl or create a conda env that has python 3.6 installed